# Cannot access Cisco ASA-5505 ASDN

Tags: cisco-asa

I just got my network up-and-running.  I would like the ASDN for some of my minions to be able to make minor changes without the need to contact me.  This said, I have tried to enable it, and access it, and it seems that I have mis-configured it.  Can anyone see what is wrong with the following config, that I can't access ASDM through `10.1.10.100`??

```
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.1.10.100 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 74.9xx.xx.225 255.255.255.248
!
ftp mode passive
pager lines 24
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 74.xx.xx.230 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
http server enable
http 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
dhcpd dns 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76
dhcpd auto_config outside
!
dhcpd address 10.1.10.104-10.1.10.254 inside
dhcpd enable inside
!

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect skinny
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect sip
  inspect netbios
  inspect tftp
  inspect ip-options
!
```

From what I gather .. I should be able to access it from anywhere on the network?  What am I missing?

Comment: you can only connect to ASDM from ip in 10.1.10.0 network if it is behind that inside interface https://<ip_address_of_inisde_interafce>

Comment: yes the PC I am trying to access it from is `10.1.10.104` which is in the `10.1.10.0` network correct?  Still when I go to `10.1.10.100` in my browser, it does not connect.

Comment: are you using https?

Comment: can you ping that inside interface from your pc?

Comment: @DanilaLadner  --  I was not placing the https://  in front of the 10.1.10.100 ...  If you'd be so kind as to explain that in an answer, I'll accept and vote up .. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `https://<ip_address_of_inisde_interafce>` should work with the config you pasted.